# Laravel 5: Retrieve data from dispatched command

Tags: php, laravel, command, laravel-5

I have a command `UploadPhotoCommand` that I have written to upload a photo to my app. The command is not self-handling and I have therefore written a handler `UploadPhotoCommandHandler` to go with it.

I dispatch the command from my controller like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Photos;

use App\Commands\Photos\UploadPhotoCommand;
use App\Http\Requests\Photos\UploadRequest;

class UploadController {

    public function process(UploadRequest $request)
    {
        try
        {
            $this->dispatch(
                new UploadPhotoCommand($request->file('photo'));
            );
        }
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            \Log::error($e);
            return response()->json(['errors' => 'Sorry, something went wrong, please try again later.']);
        }

        // I want to use the ID of the uploaded photo here
        return response()->json(['success' => 'Photo uploaded successfully']);
    }

}
```

In my command handler I handle the photo upload process by moving the uploaded image, creating a thumbnail etc. and adding a record to the database.

My problem is that I would like to retrieve the ID of the uploaded photo from the command and use it. My intention is to return more information in the response about the uploaded photo, in particular I want to return a URL using the `route` function, passing in the ID of the photo.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I've figured out a way of doing this.

For the benefit of anyone reading this in the future:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Photos;

use App\Commands\Photos\UploadPhotoCommand;
use App\Http\Requests\Photos\UploadRequest;

class UploadController {

    public function process(UploadRequest $request)
    {
        // Initialise the command to a variable
        $command = new UploadPhotoCommand($request->file('photo'));

        try
        {
            // Dispatch the command
            $this->dispatch($command);
        }
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            \Log::error($e);
            return response()->json(['errors' => 'Sorry, something went wrong, please try again later.']);
        }

        // Grab the data from the command (Command handler sets it)
        echo $command->id;

        // I want to use the ID of the uploaded photo here
        return response()->json(['success' => 'Photo uploaded successfully']);
    }

}
```

In the command handler:

```
<?php namespace App\Handlers\Commands\Photos;

use App\Commands\Photos\UploadPhotoCommand;

class UploadPhotoCommandHandler {
    public function __construct() {}

    public function handle(UploadPhotoCommand $command)
    {
        // Handle your command

        // Set the ID on the command object
        $command->id = 123;
    }
}
```

In the command:

```
<?php namespace App\Commands\Photos;

use App\Commands\Command;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

class UploadPhotoCommand extends Command {

    public $photo;

    // Declare a public property ID
    public $id;

    public function __construct(UploadedFile $photo)
    {
        $this->photo = $photo;
    }

}
```

If anyone knows of a better way of doing it, please let me know.

Comment: This is how I ended up implementing my command bus in Laravel 4. Keeping track of all the data after running the command through a stack of events was a bit of a headache for more more complex functions, but that was more a problem with my primary architecture than the basic concept, I think. Using your command as a data container that basically hoovers up data as it runs through an execution layer (or series of layers) makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way would be to have a separate function call in you UploadPhotoCommand class do the work, instead of doing it in the constructor.

This function call return a response that contains whatever you want.

I.e. you could do something like this:

```
 public function process(UploadRequest $request)
{
    try
    {
        $oPhotoUploadTask = new UploadPhotoCommand();
        $results = $oPhotoUploadTask->uploadPhoto($request->file('photo'));
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        \Log::error($e);
        return response()->json(['errors' => 'Sorry, something went wrong, please try again later.']);
    }

    // I want to use the ID of the uploaded photo here
    return response()->json(['success' => 'Photo {$results['photo_id']} uploaded successfully']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My `UploadPhotoCommand` is a DTO and I have the bulk of my code in the `UploadPhotoCommandHandler`. My command handler also benefits from dependency injection from the IoC container in the constructor and it's `handle` method is where the logic is all contained. Taking your suggested approach would mean sacrificing a range of benefits that Laravel offers which isn't really something I want to do.